# How to alias pages generated by panels (node edit or view pages)

Tags: panels, path-aliases

I have a panel page that is in the form:

"/productsByMfg/%nid" where nid is the node id of the a manufacturer.  This is not a node edit or view page since I already have that.

I have about 100 of these pages /productsByMFg/1, /productsByMfg/2 etc...
How do I create aliases so I can use something like /productsByMfg/IBM, /productsByMfg/Microsoft?

Comment: With the setup you have, I wonder why you bother at all? If you just re-use the existing node_view, path auto and token will work as usual.

Answer (score 2):

[Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) works for me. It takes care of situation like yours. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal non-administrative URLs.

Answer (score 2):

[Page Manager Pauthauto](https://drupal.org/project/page_manager_pathauto) module should take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this currently.

It's among the oldest still open [feature requests](http://drupal.org/node/615488) for Page manager. Ideally, someone would sponsor having the work done.

Currently, you'd have to write a custom module that figures out what all the possibilities are, and creates the aliases.